# jQuery UI Slider Hidden when sliding

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider

In HTML code given like this

```
<div id="slider1" class="slide1" style="overflow: visible !important; position: absolute !important; margin-top: 0px !important;"></div>
```

slider.js

```
$("#slider1").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    step: 10,
    value: 50,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $('#high').html(ui.value);
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
        $('#high').attr('value', ui.value);
    }
});
```

slide.css

```
.slide1 {
    float: left;
    left: 600px;
    height: 10px;
    width: 150px;
    top: 167px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

But I didn't even get this slider, only getting before Slider init call. When we call silder using jQuery the slider will hide due to the automatic div tag creation and its style set into `overflow: hidden`. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

How do you mean 'the first time'.

I've dropped your HTML/CSS/JS into a fiddle and it seems to work correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/2pcFh/

Listing below dropped into a file works locally for me in Firefox 13.0.1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">


      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">





      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


  <style type='text/css'>
    .slide1 {
    float: left;
    left: 600px;
    height: 10px;
    width: 150px;
    top: 167px;
    z - index: 2;
}
  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$("#slider1").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    step: 10,
    value: 50,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $('#high').html(ui.value);
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        $('#high').attr('value', ui.value);
    }
});



});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
      <div id="slider1" class="slide1" style="overflow: visible !important; position: absolute !important; margin-top: 0px !important;"></div>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Actually this slider want to place in jequery dialog box, so when clicking in slider it will hide into the frame when position:absolute,when position:fixed it will work smoothly,bt i need absolute position,when i tried ino my site it didnt show..can u show it as any other type

Comment: plz help me to avoid this automatic div creation when calling slider()